# Start called in state 4 error in android MediaPlayer?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I am starting playback of an online audio stream in a service. This is the method which starts the playback:

```
    void start1(String a){
        try{
        mp.setDataSource(a);//mp is a global MediaPlayer variable
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mp.prepareAsync();
        mp.start();
        }catch(Exception e){
            noerror=false;
                }
  }
```

The `onPrepared()` function:

```
    @Override
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp1){
        mp.start();
    }
```

This code gives me the error

```
Start called in state 4: error(-38,0)
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove this line

```
mp.start();
```

from your `start1` method since you're already starting playing in the `onPrepared` method.

Answer (score 1):

State 4 means `Mediaplayer` is in preparing state

and we call other actions like

```
Mediaplayer.start() 
Mediaplayer.stop() 
Mediaplayer.pause()
```

or any other.

As per your code, it is Mediaplayer.start();

Once Onprepared() method is called you can do the further processing.

Just remove

```
mp.start()
```

after

```
mp.prepareAsync();
```

And you will be good to go!